# Space Engineers Terminal Hacking

Tags: space-engineers

With online play, is it easy to hack other players ships?

To hack in single player is fairly easy:

1. install a terminal
2. access it
3. within the control panel press ctrl + a
4. then transfer to: "me".

The list above can be tedious online and take hours to test, that's why I'm asking.

My goal is to have something either automated (not likely) or a vessel with a crew to hack enemy players while a battle is in progress. Can easily be an "Achilles heel" to even the strongest structures, if it works that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure about that since I never tried it, but I found something on the Steam forum that could help you:

> It depends. If you are talking multiplayer you must hack the main control seat to fly it. But then you must hack each block that contains computers. There is no shortcut for that.

You can find the whole discussion [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/244850/discussions/0/364041517007137133/). Hope it helps!

Comment: I wonder if it has changed within the past few years. I'll try it eventually, free time is an asset I have little of. Truly appreciate the research.